# set the color of Edit Part objects (Figures) in GEF

Tags: java, emf, eclipse-gef

I need to set the color of certain paths that has objects of a model in a plugin tool. i set of editpart (figures)corresponding to the target model elements(EMF).However, the color of the editpart figures is changed to its default (black) whenever  i click, reposition the elements on the screen, or navigate the editors. I need the color to be fixed and not changed when such an event (click, move, etc) happens. Any help please !!

Here is the code i used :

```
for(EObject element:visitedNodes)
{
//Here i get the edit part related to a particular model element    
modelEditPart=(EditPart)viewer.getEditPartRegistry().get((EObject)element );
if(modelEditPart!=null)
{
//set the color of the figure
( (GraphicalEditPart)
modelEditPart).getFigure().setForegroundColor(ColorConstants.green);
}
```

Comment: Any help ? all i need is to set the color of the figures permenantly

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set any colours in #refresh() and/or #refreshVisuals() methods in your editpart class.